# Absurd size and quantity of byte[] while profiling

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, profiling

I have been having an out of memory problem with one of my webapps and fired up Eclipse's TPTP to find it. I was shocked to the that the biggest offender was byte[] with an ever increasing number of instances and size. Is there any way to track down where that is coming from? For reference my software stack is Java 1.5, tomcat 5.5 and spring 2.5.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: That cartoon is the greatest!

Comment: @Mike the one on my profile? Yup, it's great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`byte[]` instances will be coming from network communications (transferring socket data through JNI), image processing (storing the data of `BufferedImages`), and any other non-native `ByteBuffers` you have. It'd be useful to know the type of application you have :) (edit: just noticed Tomcat and Spring. I'd go for network communications)

Comment: Wow, that was it. My cache was pulling down a pile of data from a remote source. Thanks.